# How to I make these 2D images visible with the mist in the render?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, shaders, image, effects

I tried to make a polygonal render of a forest but when I test rendered it, the leaf texture I used for the trees only show in the tree area. Is there any way I can make it visible like the other objects?

[image]

---

How I used the mist in the scene [image]

---

If there's any thing I can do here, let me know

[image: Here is another screenshot]

Comment: Are you using the compositor to add the mist? Can you show how is the mist applied to the scene?

Comment: I suspect you have mixed the materials to make the branch visible in the tree texture. And the branches themselves look like seperate objects that might be turned off in the render view? If you could provide the .blend file we could have a look. Upload your file here: [Blend-Exchange.com](https://blend-exchange.com/)